# Why is it giving a warning?

Tags: kotlin

[image]

I replaced it with Val and the texts did not go away.
Edit: Changing it manually fixed it. But why "var" is it giving an error?

"Variable is never modified so it can be declared using 'val'"

Comment: Have you rebuilt or revalidated after changing `var` to `val`?

Comment: When I change it manually and run it, it fixes itself, but when I make it var, it breaks again.

Comment: if you get a warning for `X`, and you change it to the correct `Y`. Of course that you will get a warning again if you change it back to `X` afterwards.

Comment: No, that's not the problem, I want to know why var is problem for int, double...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In many languages, compile time validation yields information about the mutability of variables. Variables that do not change value during the execution of a function are invariables. In Kotlin (and some other languages) it is highly recommended to mark those invariables as such (by using the keyword `val` instead of `var`).

If you use `val`, then this has two consequences.

1. The obvious one is, that the value cannot change any longer. If you try to assign a new value later on, the compiler will yield a compile time error, and you must either assign the new value somewhere else, or change the `val` back to `var`. This ensures, that the original value is not accidentally changed.

```
{
    val pi = 3.141d
    for (...
        pi = 3 // This will not compile
    )
}
```

2. The less obvious effect is, that any reader of the scope will *immediately see* that the value will never change during the scope's existence. This is a great benefit in readability, as it signals any reader that variable changes happen elsewhere.

```
{
    val myMessage = "..."
    ...
    // Here I can be sure that myMessage is still "..."
}
```

It is therefore useful to mark invariables as `val`, as it helps read and understand the code and adds to safety in execution.

Comment: Thanks for sparing time. I took note of these.

Comment: *the compiler will throw an exception* - mmh sorry for nitpicking, but I guess it would be a bit clearer to say that "the code will not compile", or "you'll get a compile error". But if the compiler actually throws an exception, it's probably a bug :)

Comment: @joffrey You are not wrong, though I have never heard anyone distinguish this. What would you call an illegal reassignment? It is not syntactically wrong, so it is not even a compile time error. It happens later, either during token-resolution or semantic interpretation, I am not sure in this point. // I changed it to something more formally correct.

Comment: @TreffnonX compile time errors are not just about syntax, it's about any error that you get during the compilation (as opposed to during runtime). This includes all the steps of the compilation. The compiler not only checks the syntax, but also the types, names, imports, visibility etc. Illegal assignments are definitely part of compile time errors, for any reason (`val`, type mismatch, setter visibility etc.).

Comment: @Joffrey Ok, that seems to be the general definition indeed. So I guess compile time error is a very good fit for this situation. I will change it to match.

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin, `var` denotes a variable that can be reassigned different values, while `val` denotes a variable that cannot.

If you never reassign a `var`, it's better to show that you don't need this by using `val` instead. The compiler can do better optimizations and in particular smart casts with `val`s.

As a rule of thumb: if the compiler doesn't force you to use `var`, use `val`.

Comment: Any chance of giving a real example? Like the category or title name that doesn't change on the app?

Comment: @RecepORTAC 99% of my local variables are `val`, I almost never reassign anything in my code. Reassigning for the purpose of maintaining state in loops can usually be avoided by using proper functional operators on collections. Reassigning a simple variable after modification is often a smell, it's better to declare a new variable with a name that reflects in which way it is different. etc. etc. It might be better for you if we could instead find examples where you would actually need `var`: mutable properties of a class are a good example.